# inserting data in table via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in my index.html file

```
<table id="userTable">
      <tr>
        <th>UserId</th>
        <th>About you</th>
        <th>Age Max</th>
        <th>Age Min</th>
        <th>City</th>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Im using firebase to pull some data down to display it in the table.

```
  snapshot.forEach(snap => {
    console.log(snap.val())
    var r = document.getElementById('userTable').insertRow().innerHTML = snap.val().username
    var x = r.insertCell(1);
    x.innerHTML = snap.val().age
  })
```

The firebase logic is working correct, i am able to get the desired fields, but i can't seem to insert the data into a column for that row.

Im getting an error:

```
TypeError: r.insertCell is not a function. (In 'r.insertCell(1)', 'r.insertCell' is undefined)
```

The plan is to create a row and then populate the columns with the rest of the data.

Comment: What do you expect `r` to hold and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two assignments in this line:

`var r = document.getElementById('userTable').insertRow().innerHTML = snap.val().username`

I'm not sure what the value of `r` is in this case, but it's not a `HTMLTableRowElement` which is why you're getting that `TypeError`. You need to call insertCell on a `HTMLTableRowElement` object. See this documentation for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell